# List Comments based on visualforce page ID

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, community

I have a visualforce detail page that utilizes a link like:
https://org-developer-edition.na17.force.com/MyCommunity/Page_Detail?id=a00o0000007FxHjSSK

I am trying to construct a controller that would allow me to display a record from a custom object (Idea Comments) with a master-detail relationship to the standard controller object (Idea Lobby) based on the ID of the displayed record.

Here is my extension so far:

```
public with sharing class detExt {
public detExt(ApexPages.StandardController acon) { }
  public List<Idea_Comments__c> getdetExt()
    {
        return [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, Comment__c
        FROM Idea_Comments__c
        order by CreatedDate DESC ];
    }
}
```

I only want the Idea Comment records with the master-detail relationship to the specific record to show up.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the ID of the record from the standard controller. then you can filter on that value like this (varies depending on your use case)

```
public with sharing class detExt {

private Id theID; 

public detExt(ApexPages.StandardController acon) {

   theID = acon.getID();

 }
  public List<Idea_Comments__c> getdetExt()
    {
        return [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, Comment__c
        FROM Idea_Comments__c
        WHERE FIELDNAME = :theID
        order by CreatedDate DESC ];
    }
}
```

Or if you need to access the standard Controller in many places for various purposes throughout your code you could:

```
public with sharing class detExt {

private ApexPAges.StandardController theController; 

public detExt(ApexPages.StandardController acon) {

   theController = acon;

 }
  public List<Idea_Comments__c> getdetExt()
    {

        ID masterID = theController.getID();

        return [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, Comment__c
        FROM Idea_Comments__c
        WHERE FIELDNAME = :masterID
        order by CreatedDate DESC ];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Btuitasi - FielName should be FieldName - Replace it with the API name of the relationship field on the Idea_Comments__c object

Comment: Thanks!! I only have one problem now though. If I view the page as a preview: https://c.na13.visual.force.com/apex/Page_Detail?id=a00o0000004Hq3lAAC         I can see the record displayed, but when I go out to the community to view: https://org-developer-edition.na17.force.com/community/page_Detail?id=a00o0000004Hq3lAAC, I see the field labels and no data.

Comment: @Btuitasi - I am assuming you are using Input fields? if so, then check the permissions as they may not have edit ability on those fields. Or maybe you are using outputFields with custom labels, again check permissions to see if they have visibility for those fields. They = profile

Comment: I am using output fields. I have found the problem though. My guest user profile didn't have access to my custom object. Thanks for all the help!!